# Using Math.max with typed subarrays

Tags: javascript, performance, typed-arrays

I have a typed array filled with values.

I am trying to figure out the fastest way to calculate the max and min of those values in any given boundary.

So for example, I have 3200 values and I want to know the max value of the range between index 342 and 934, the boundary range can change and reach from a 1000 values to check on to multiple ten thousands.

I thought that something like this would work:

```js
const a = new Uint8Array([10, 60, 5, 90, 110, 3, 45, 1, 24, 54, 29]);
Math.max(...a.subarray(5, 7)); // Returns 45.
```

But as far as I remember, the spread operator is super slow.

I actually thought that the `Math.max` function also takes an array but using

```js
Math.max(a.subarray(5, 7));
```

returns `NaN`.

Has anybody an idea on what the most performant way would be to get the maximum of any given range? I am especially looking for high performance on large views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) takes any number of arguments, so you can use `Math.max.apply` (see [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)) to pass it an array:

```js
const a = new Uint8Array([10, 60, 5, 90, 110, 3, 45, 1, 24, 54, 29]);
var max = Math.max.apply(null,a.subarray(5, 7));
console.log(max);
```

But the absolute fastest appears to be :

```js
const a = new Uint8Array([10, 60, 5, 90, 110, 3, 45, 1, 24, 54, 29]);
var sa = a.subarray(5, 7);
var max = -Infinity;
for(var i=0;i<sa.length;i++)
   if(sa[i] > max) max = sa[i];
console.log(max);
```

Benchmark results: https://jsbench.me/92kfgj7ldx/1

Comment: Is this the fastest possible way?

Comment: @JohannesKlauß I benchmarked this and the spread and this came out better. I can't personally think of anything that could possibly be faster

Comment: @JohannesKlauß tell a lie,I found what appears to be a quicker way

Comment: Oh nice, gonna check that out for larger arrays

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative which you can use.

```
const a = new Uint8Array([10, 60, 5, 90, 110, 3, 45, 1, 24, 54, 29]);
Math.max.apply({}, a.subarray(5, 7));
```

I tried running benchmarks on [jsbench](https://jsben.ch/bisDq) and these were the results:

```
code block 1 (1404013)

code block 2 (1695631)
```

This is how apply works as per [specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3)